# Add CSS Class for each tr Element if it contains specific value

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I'm trying to add a class to an tr element (last_value_row) in a form when the target value in the first td of the last_value_row element is "New Target".
So far only the first Element will add the class, but not every other element where the target value is "New Target".

This is my HTML-side:

```
<table id="epoch_forms_table" class="epoch_forms_table">
   <tr class="title_row">
      <th>{% autoescape off %}{% trans "Target name" %}{% endautoescape %}</th>
      ...
      <th class="last"></th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="value_row{% if epoch_form.errors %} error{% endif %}">
      <td></td>
      <td><label><input type="number" size="13" step="0.001"></label></td>
      <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="button icon remove remove_row_button danger"></a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="last_value_row" class="last_value_row target_background_color">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="{{ key }}_unit unit" id="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="error_row">
      {% for field in epoch_form %}
         <td>{{ field.errors }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my JavaScript-side:

```
var new_target_element = document.getElementById("last_value_row");
var last_values = [];
var index = $("#epoch_forms_table tr.value_row").index(value_row);


...
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   for (let i = 0, cell; cell = new_target_element.cells[i]; i++) {
      if ($(this).find("td:contains('New target')")) {
         new_target_element.classList.add("new_target_color");
         new_target_element.classList.remove("target_background_color");
      } else {
         new_target_element.classList.add("target_background_color");
         new_target_element.classList.remove("new_target_color");
      }
   }
}
 if (last_values[index].length === 0) {
            last_value_row.find("td:first").html("New target");
        } else {
...
}
}
```

I'm trying to add or remove the CSS-Class "new_target_color" to every "last_value_row" when there is or isn't a target value "New Target" in the first td. So far, only the first element will always change it's class.

Comment: what do you mean by target value? trs have no value. You also want to look into `classList.toggle()` which has a 2nd parameter such as: `element.classList.toggle('class', condition)`. That will apply to the class only if the condition is true and remove it otherwise.

Comment: I mean the target value of the first td in the tr element (last_value_row).
I want to change the class for each tr element, when the td element of the last_value_row is New Target.
Sorry if I it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: _"So far only the first Element will add the class, but not every other element"_ - what "other" elements? Are you saying, that you have _multiple_ `<tr id="last_value_row" ...>` elements? Then this is the first _error_ you need to fix - IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Please get into the habit of providing a proper [mre] with this type of question. First of all, we don't have your server-side setup or your data available - so we can't tell for sure, what your server-side _templating code_, that you have shown us as "this is the HTML", will actually produce. You want to discuss a client-side problem here, so anything server-side is of rather little interest - show us the _resulting_ HTML, please, instead of your templating code.

Comment: And second, don't show snippets that clearly lack context, such as `for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++)` - how are we supposed to know, what you are even looping over here to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I think your row with an **ID** of last_value_row is a bit of a red herring, you actually want to find rows with a class of this (otherwise you're looking for a series of unique values, or getting into nth child territory).

```js
// Select all rows with class 'last_value_row'
var lastValueRows = document.querySelectorAll('.last_value_row');

// Function to add or remove classes based on the content
function updateRowClasses(row) {
    // Check if the first cell contains 'New Target'
    var isFirstCellNewTarget = row.cells[0].textContent.trim() === 'New Target';

    // Add or remove classes based on the condition
    if (isFirstCellNewTarget) {
        row.classList.add("new_target_color");
        row.classList.remove("target_background_color");
    } else {
        row.classList.remove("new_target_color");
        row.classList.add("target_background_color");
    }
}

// Iterate over each 'last_value_row' and apply the function
lastValueRows.forEach(updateRowClasses);
```